# How can I uninstall iphone development sdk on mac

Tags: iphone, macos

I download iphone sdk for 10.5 from
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action#downloads

How can I uninstall it but leave XCode untouch?
Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Delete the following directories:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform

Removing these will delete iPhone-specific libraries and tools, but leave you with XCode and everything necessary to write applications for the Mac.